# "Your info" in Windows 10 account settings showing old profile picture in addition to new one

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I changed my Microsoft account's profile picture yesterday. After that it's showing my old picture to the right of my new one. Not a big issue. But it's irritating.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly it is that you find irritating?

Comment: The duplicate account thing. It's actually the same account.

Comment: Do you mean that there are two profile pictures? That doesn't mean there are two different accounts, it's a way of allowing you to use your old picture instead of your new one. If you click on your old picture, it will change your picture back. I don't know how to disable that feature though.

Comment: This is a feature?! Wo! Who wanted that feature actually? By the way. Thanks.